# UNIX: How to print contents of variable with formatting.

Tags: unix, csh

I just want to print ls -l the same way it looks from the command line (each file on a new line). I have looked every where for a solution and know my solution *should* work but for some reason it doesn't. I have tried:

```
    #!/bin/csh
    set list = `ls -l`
    echo "$list"
```

and:

```
    #!/bin/csh
    set list = "`ls -l`"
    echo "$list"
```

with no luck. What I really want to do is use grep on ls -l later (so maby I'm going about this wrong), but I can't because it prints list as one long line. 
(and yes, I have to use csh)

Comment: Why can't you do `/bin/sh -c "whatever"` in your csh script?

Comment: @Kevin That doesn't change my out put at all. Why is that supposed to work?

Comment: Well, you said you can only use csh, but you can run Bourne shell commands by using `/bin/sh -c`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how to get around csh's behaviour of joining words together when you `echo`, but you may be able to use array-like functionality and a loop.  For example:

```
#!/bin/csh

set list=( "`printf 'a\nb\nc\n'`" )

echo "count=$#list"
echo "2 = $list[2]"
echo

set n=0
while ( $n < $#list )
    @ n += 1
    echo "$n : $list[$n]"
end
```

Which for me produces the output:

```
count=3
2 = b

1 : a
2 : b
3 : c
```

Note that I'm using tcsh on FreeBSD. Your csh may be different, you haven't mentioned your platform.

To bring this back to your list of files question, you can replicate the output you're looking for with a similar loop:

```
#!/bin/csh

set list=( "`ls -l`" )
set n=0
while ( $n < $#list )
    @ n += 1
    echo "$list[$n]"
end
```

The important consideration here is that within (command substitution) backquotes (`` `...` ``), output is word-separated by *whitespace*, whereas inside double quotes (`"..."`), output is word-separated by *newlines*.

That said...

> What I really want to do is use grep on ls -l later (so maby I'm going about this wrong), but I can't because it prints list as one long line.

Entirely possible!  :-)  But without a full understanding of the underlying problem you're trying to solve, helping you achieve *your* solution is the best we can do.  Beware the dreaded [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).